# replace block of text in file linux

Tags: bash, sed

I want to remove block of text in file.

file

```
      .
      .
      .
 "chromedriver": {
      "version": "80.0.2",
      .
      .
      .
   }
     },
 "ci-env": {
      .
      .
      .
```

I want remove attribute chromedriver witch is define in multiple lines.

I tried this:

`sed -i 's/"chromedriver"(\s|\n|.)*"ci-env":/"ci-env":/g' file`

but it doesn't work. There is a oneliner that can resolve my problem? Is sed can do this?

Comment: is it a json file? can you show more content? anyway, when working with json, [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is much more better suited than `sed`, `awk` and other line oriented unix tools.

Answer (score 1):

Using `jq`, which as mentioned in a comment is the better approach for dealing with JSON:

```
jq 'del(.chromedriver)' file > file.tmp && mv -f file.tmp file
```

(Guessing at the appropriate path here because your example data is way too sketchy)

Answer (score 0):

Ed to the rescue!

```
#!/bin/sh

cat >> edcut.txt << EOF
/chromedriver/
ka
/ci-env/
-1
kb
'a,'bd
wq
EOF

ed -s file.json < edcut.txt
```

if you wanted to extract the record to another file, replace 'a,'bd with 'a,'bW newfile.txt.